# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-4}^{4} |x| \ dx$

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I have to evaluate the integral

> $$\int_{-4}^{4} |x| \mathrm{d}x$$

I have 2 answers but I don't know what a correct answer :

My first answer:

$$\int_{-4}^{4} |x| \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{parity}{=} 2\int_{0}^{4} x \mathrm{d}x={2x^2 \over2 }\bigg|_{0}^{4}=16$$

My second answer :

$$\int_{-4}^{4} |x|\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-4}^{0} (-x) \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{4} x \mathrm{d}x=-8+8=0$$

So my question is: **What is the correct answer?**

Comment: check whether the -8 is correct

Comment: How do get to the $\int\limits_{-4}^{0}(-x)dx=-8$ in your second answer?

Comment: check which answer has to be wrong by thinking about the graph, it has to be two triangles above the x axis, there has to be area only above the x axis and it cannot be zero

Comment: In fact $\int_{-4}^{0}{(-x)dx}=8$.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\int_{-4}^0(\color{red}{-}x)dx&=\color{red}{-}\int_{-4}^0xdx\\
&=\color{red}{-}\frac{x^2}{2}\Big|_{x=-4}^{0}\\
&=\color{red}{-}\left(\frac{0^2}{2}-\frac{(-4)^2}{2}\right)\\
&=8
\end{align}

Comment: If you use \left and \right instead of \big, then the brackets will automatically scale to the right size.

Comment: @wythagoras You are right. I somehow do not like the left/right idea when there is no need for a really Big bracket. Big Big is the same for left and right and somehow matches my ordering of things :-) in simpler ways.

Answer (score 2):

You get the following 
$$\int_{-4}^{4} |x| \ dx = \int_{-4}^0 (-x) dx + \int_0^4 x dx = \left[-\frac 1 2 x^2\right]_{-4}^0 + \left[\frac 1 2 x^2\right]_0^4 = 8 + 8 = 16$$
I hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to compute such simple integrals by areas of regions. Here we have identic triangles. One of them has vertices $(0,0),(4,0),(4,4)$, so its area is $8$. That's why our integral equals $16$.

Answer (score 0):

For variety: The function $F(x) = \dfrac{x|x|}{2}$ is an antiderivative of $f(x) = |x|$, so
$$
\int_{-4}^{4} |x|\, dx
  = \frac{x|x|}{2}\bigg|_{x=-4}^{4}
  = \frac{16}{2} - \left(-\frac{16}{2}\right)
  = 16.
$$
As other have noted, the sign error occurred in the evaluation of the integral from $-4$ to $0$, where you're subtracting a negative.